# Where in Chile can I learn to dive with a hose (surface supplied diving)?

Tags: chile, diving

I don't really know how much of a learning curve there really is compared to diving with a tank. So, where in Chile can I experience to dive with a hose and an air compressor? Preferably within a safe environment / with a diving instructor and not a crazy fisherman.

Answer (score 2):

If you Google for the Spanish term "escuela de buceo comercial chile", on of the top five hits is [this school here](http://www.escuelabuceoneptuno.com/?cat=5), which offers such courses. they take 6 weeks. They are located in Talcahuano, Chile.

You need to consider that surface supplied diving is very expensive and complicated. The equipment required for this is a huge factor in this. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_supplied_diving) for more info. Scuba can be learned in 3 days instead for example. You will be learning a new profession, not a hobby.

Comment: Thanks. I learned just now that there are two kinds of surface supplied diving, of which one is the professional kind you linked to. The other seems to be a more introductory way to diving (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snuba ). The fishermen here, as in many places, use a simple setup with a hose and an air compressor. I'm not sure if they have proper regulators or if they simply bite the hose. But the details between these setups doesn't seem very travel related :)